# How to return a response if pagination does not exist on a page

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This appears to be a rather simple one but I can't tell exactly why I am not getting it right.
I have website pages with similar content but the difference is that some of these pages contain pagination while the rest has no pagination. for pages with pagination, I am sending a request to follow all pagination links, while for the pages without pagination, I simply want to return the response the way it is.

Example links with and without pagination

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2008/results/

https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/africa/africa-cup-of-nations-2021/results/

How can I yield or return the original response for pages without pagination in the   `else` statement

```
 def check_paginated_pages(self,response): 
     cookies = response.data['cookies']  
     headers = response.data['headers'] 
     next_page = response.xpath("//* 
     [@id='pagination']/a[last()-1]//@href").extract_first() 
     print('Next page ------------------------', response.urljoin(next_page))  
     if next_page is not None:`    
         yield SplashRequest(url= response.url, callback=self.follow_teams, 
                      cookies=cookies, headers=headers, endpoint='execute'  
                      args={'lua_source': self.lua_pagination_script,'wait':2, 
                     'timeout':90,'images':0}, errback=self.errback_httpbin 
                                        )
     else: 
          print('When next page is None------------------------------------', response.url)  
          yield from self.follow_teams(response) 

  def follow_teams(self,response):
      cookies = response.data['cookies']
      headers = response.data['headers']
```

Comment: are you intentioanlly requesting the same page over and over again?  your `yield SplashRequest` statement has `response.url` as the url, which is like saying you want scrapy to request the same url over and over....

Comment: @Alexander I am only requesting pages with pagination over again because I want to go through the pagination links. For pages without pagination `else`, I can easily request those pages again by using `SplashRequest(url=response.url`) in the `else` statement but I have the response already. How can I parse the response to `follow_teams` function?

Comment: Scrappy has a duplicate filter so that might be what the problem is, but I still don't understand why you would need to request the same page over again instead of requesting the the next page?

Comment: @Alexander I didn't add a duplicate filter because I don't want to send the same request multiple times. I simply want to return `html` response of within my function.